# Understanding the proof .

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, modular-forms

First of all some notations :

$M_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$  denotes the set of all modular forms of weight k 
on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $ .

For every even $k\geq 4$

$$E_k(z)=1-\frac{2k}{B_k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma_{k-1
}(n)q^n$$

is a modular form of weight k for the full modular group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $
satisfying $E_k(i\infty)=1$ .

Now the exercise :

Let $r_k=\dim M_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ and $l=k-12r_k+12$ . For any modular form $f \in M_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z})) $ , show that

$$fE_l^{-1} \in  M_{12r_k-12}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z})).$$

Proof : Since $f \in M_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ , it is a linear combination of
$$ E_4^aE_6^b$$
such that $4a + 6b = k$. Now $E_l^{-1}=\frac{E_{14-l}}{E_{14}}$ , so that 
$ fE_l^{-1}$ is a linear combination of terms like
$$ E_4^aE_6^b \frac{E_{14-l}}{E_{14}}. \tag1 \label1$$

We have $E_{14}=E_4^2E_6$ and $E_{14-l}$ is one of $E_0, E_4,E_6,E_8,E_{10}$ or $E_{14}$. Recalling that

$E_8^2=E_4^2$ and $E_{10}=E_4E_6$, we see that $\frac{E_{14-l}}{E_{14}}$ is one of $\frac{1}{E_4^2E_6} ,\frac{1}{E_4E_6},\frac{1}{E_4^2},\frac{1}{E_6}$ , or $1$.

If $a\geq 2,b\geq1$ , then the term in(1) is holomorphic .

Thus, we need only consider the five cases
$$(a,b) \in \lbrace(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1) \rbrace .$$

But in all these cases , $r_k=1 $ so that $l=k\leq14$ and the result is evident.

1. Why can I not say that f is a modular form of weight k and $E_l$ is one of weight l so that the quotient is of weight $k-l=12r_k-12$?
2. In the proof why is $E_{14-l}$ one of $E_0,E_4...$
   Is it because $4a+6b=k$?
   I think $\frac{E_{14-l}}{E_{14}}$ can also be $\frac{1}{E_4}$.
3. Why do we have to consider the case (2,1)? I thought for this case (1) is  already holomorphic.
4. Why is the result evident? Because $fE_l^{-1}$ is of weight 0 ?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: If $f\in M_k(SL_2(Z)),g\in M_l(SL_2(Z))$ then $f/g$ is a meromorphic modular form, the obstruction to being a modular form are its poles. When removing the holomorphy conditions the modular forms are not finite dimensional anymore and we don't have the Petersson inner product, the normality of Hecke operators, nor the decomposition in eigenforms.